# angular14 cli test config to pass karma conf file

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular14

How to pass karma config file in angular cli command to run unit test in angular 14. I am trying to apps `--karmaConfig=karma.ci.js` but its not working

Answer (score 0):

The Karma config param in the command line is changed in angular 14 now.

old: `--karmaConfig=karma.ci.js`
new: `--karma-config=karma.ci.js`